# Getting Error while trying to update az module using VSCODE and Powershell 7 local install

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, az

I am trying to update powershell az module using VS Code and it gives me the error attached. Tried the same from VS Code, still the same[image]

Comment: set-executionpolicy remotesigned

Comment: I used -skippublishercheck and that worked. But now i have two versions of Az modules, how do i remove the older verions of Az modules from my system and ensure that i have only the latest version installed